# Firestore rule on condition from a different collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore db with two collections: users and tournaments.  The users have a 'participant' role and an 'admin' role and are indicated by 'isParticipant' and 'isAdmin' booleans in the user document:

```
/users/{userId}:
  isParticipant: true
  isAdmin: true
```

I have access rules set up for these collections like so:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /users/{userId} {
      allow create, read;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
     match /tournaments/{tournamentId} {
      allow create, read, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, what I really want to do is restrict the creation of a tournament to a user that is of an 'admin' role.  I am already doing this in code, but would like the added security of a db rule to prevent anyone but an admin user from creating a tournament.

Is there a way to reference the data element of a different collection within the rules syntax?  Something like:

```
     match /tournaments/{tournamentId} {
      allow create: if resources.users.userId.isAdmin == true;
    }
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the data in a different collection by using the `get` function:

> ```
>  // Allow the user to delete cities if their user document has the
>  // 'admin' field set to 'true'
>  allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
> ```

For more information on this, see [access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in the Firebase documentation, which is where I got the above example from.

One thing to note is that this requires an additional document read. If you'd store the fact that a user is an admin *inside* their profile as a custom claim, you could access it from `request.auth` without needing an extra read. E.g.

```
allow delete: if request.auth.token.admin == true
```

For more on this, see [control access with custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) and [accessing the user token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about the custom claim feature.  Are the claims visible anywhere in the Firestore console?  i.e. would I be able to change the value of a claim without having to do it programmatically?

Comment: I don't think these claims show up in the console, but that would make a great [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). Right now you'll have to get them through the Admin SDK, or in the client.