# How to grant collection access to user based in other collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's assume that there is 3 collections and they are at the same hierarchy level:

1. User
2. UserAndOtherCollectionRelationship
3. OtherCollection

I desire to grant access on "OtherCollection" records to the users that own that record or are related to it (only read access).

Understand "UserAndOtherCollectionRelationship" as

```
UserAndOtherCollectionRelationship: {
    'userId': uid, //user id provided by Firebase Auth Service
    'otherCollectionId': 000,
    'roles': ['owner', 'reader', ...]
}
```

This is what I have:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

  match /otherCollection/{otherCollectionId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if(isOtherCollectionOwner());
    allow create: if(isSignedIn());
  }

  match /user/{userId} {
    allow read, write: if(isSignedIn() && isUserOwner(userId));
  }

  match /userAndOtherCollectionRelationship/{userAndOtherCollectionRelationshipId} {
    allow read: if(resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid && isSignedIn());
    allow create: if(isSignedIn());
    allow update, delete: if(resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid);
  }

  // Functions
  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  function isUserOwner(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
  }

  function isOtherCollectionOwner() {
    return isUserOwner(getUserAndOtherCollectionRelationshipData().userId) && getOtherCollectionData().roles.hasAll(['owner']);
  }

  //This is the function that I believe that it's not working propertly
  function getuserAndOtherCollectionRelationshipData() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userAndOtherCollectionRelationship/{document=**}).data; 
  }
}
```

---

Considering that the client (the app) must create a filter (where clause) to get only the desired records, I could not find a way to do that with this schema too.

So I put the user roles as a field on the "otherCollection" record:

```
otherCollection: {
    ...,
    'userAndRoles': {
        'replaceByUID': ['owner', ...]
    },
}
```

updated the security rule function to:

```
function isOtherCollectionOwner() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/OtherCollection/$(otherCollectionId)).data.roles[request.auth.uid].hasAll(['owner']);
}
```

Here is the client call:

```
final querySnapshot = await firestore.collection('otherCollection')
    .where('user.$userId', arrayContains: 'owner')
    .where('otherCollectionId', whereIn: otherCollectionIdList)
    .get();
```

What is the best solution?
Change the data model to...
Set a different security rule as...

Comment: Please take a look into the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629285/8791788) by a Googler for the same concern.

Comment: That doesn't fit to my need because on his case the user is admin to the role system, every record will understand that user as admin.

In my case, the user is owner/admin only to some records on the "otherCollection"

Answer (score 0):

When a user wants to access an another collection, we have to set a rule under that collection.

So when you create a document in a collection, you have to create the same id in the other collection and create a field called owner.
This field **owner** contains the uid of the person who created the document.

```
userAndOtherCollectionRelationshipId === otherCollectionId
  UserAndOtherCollectionRelationship: {
    'owner': uid
}
```

In this way, when a user try to read the document, we check if he is owner or not with **isOwner(otherCollectionId, request.auth.uid)** function with Collectionid, and the userId. In the function you check if the owner who created the document is the same who is trying to read the document.

You can do create a rule as following:

```
match /otherCollection/{otherCollectionId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if isOwner(otherCollectionId, request.auth.uid);
    allow create: if isSignedIn();
}
function isOwner(docId, userId) {
   return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userAndOtherCollectionRelationship/$(docId)).data.owner == userId;
}
```

Comment: This solution uses the otherCollectionId as the userAndOtherCollectionRelationshipId, because isOwner function receives the otherCollectionId when you call for it.

This way it's possible to create only one otherCollection to one userAndOtherCollectionRelationship.

The collection userAndOtherCollectionRelationship was created exactly to allow many users to be related to otherCollection.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I updated the data model removing the userAndOtherCollectionRelationship collection and add the owner attribute to the otherCollection.

Any other relationship would be added as an attribute to otherCollection.

So the otherCollection looks like this now:

```
otherCollection: {
    owner: ["user_uid", "other_user_id"],
    ..., //other atributes
}
```

The security rules were updated to:

```
match /otherCollection/{otherCollectionId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if(isOtherCollectionOwner());
    allow create: if(isSignedIn());
}
function isOtherCollectionOwner() {
  return ([request.auth.uid] in (resource.data.owner));
}
```

The security rules tests were updated to:

```
const myAuth = {uid: 'my_user_uid', email: 'my@mail.com'};
const MY_PROJECT_ID = "my_project_id";

function getAdminFirestore() {
    return firebase.initializeAdminApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: myAuth}).firestore();
}

function getFirestore(auth) {
    return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: auth}).firestore();
}

describe("MyApp", () => {
    it("Can list if is owner", async () => {
        const admin = getAdminFirestore();
        const setupOtherCollection = admin.collection('otherCollection').doc('otherCollectionId');
        await setupOtherCollection.set({'name': 'myOtherCollection', 'owner': [myAuth.uid]});
    
        const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
        const otherCollectionCollection = db.collection("otherCollection").where("owner", "array-contains", [myAuth.uid]);
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(otherCollectionCollection.get());
    });
});
```