# Firestore security rule that checks field under random document in collection to allow update in other collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a project that was created without any security and I am trying to lock things down to acceptable levels.
It's an Angular/Ionic app using AngularFire.

Issues started when locking down users writes to the user itself, because the application contains a chat function.
When a chat message is created, the application code uses a batch write to update both involved users, of which the latter obbviously fails.
The batch write code looks like:

```
const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();

const sellerUserDoc = this.db.firestore.collection(this.collectionId()).doc(this.toUserDocId(sellerExtendedUser));
batch.set(sellerUserDoc, this.createExtendedUserOfferConversationUpdateItem(sellerExtendedUser, offerConversation), { merge: true });

const buyerUserDoc = this.db.firestore.collection(this.collectionId()).doc(this.toUserDocId(buyerExtendedUser));
batch.set(buyerUserDoc, this.createExtendedUserOfferConversationUpdateItem(buyerExtendedUser, offerConversation), { merge: true });

return batch.commit();
```

My question is about how to add a security rule / modify query or other code that allows another user to be written to, if a conversation exist between them.

Currently a conversation is created in the conversations collection, with a random ID, which contains both user ids.

Then there is the users collection, which has a map of conversation, that currently does not get populated with the ID because of the rules/query.

I have spend hours watching videos, posts here, and trying thigns out without succes.
I think my main problem is that when a user update gets done, I am unable to get the conversation ID ( and I got the message that security rules are not filters :) ).

This is an example of an attempt with non working findings commented out( I am using the emulator on a dev machine):

```
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id || isConvPartner(); 
  allow read,update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id ||  getConversations(request.auth.uid)
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
}

function isConvPartner() {
      let isBuyer = get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents).data.buyerId == request.auth.uid;
      let isSeller = get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(resource.data.id)).data.sellerId == request.auth.uid;

      return isBuyer || isSeller
}

function getConversations(uid){
  let conversationsForuser = get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents).data.values.buyerId.hasAny(uid);

match /{prefix=**}/staging-v1-conversations/{docId} {
  allow read,write,update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.buyerId 
  || request.auth.uid == resource.data.sellerId 
  || request.data.id == resource.data.id
  || get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(docId)).data.buyerId == request.auth.uid
  || get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(docId)).data.sellerId == request.auth.uid
  || resource == null
  || request.auth != null;
  allow create: if request.resource.data.buyerId == request.auth.uid || request.resource.data.sellerId == request.auth.uid;

  function recipeData() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(docId)).data.buyerId == request.auth.id
  }
}
  return conversationsForuser

}
```

I thought about modifying the way data is written, but I cannot really think of a way to write this data to another user then either - the rule has to allow it.
Is this the correct approach and how should the security rules look like precisely?

Some pictures from the emulator to show the database structure:

[image: conversations]

[image: users]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

[update]
I am trying to use the following function to allow the second user to be updated:

```
function getConvForUser(loggedInId,userId){
  let user =  loggedInId;
  let userFetched = user-MYkirTsKsmCNevww40IzQpn0m6fX;//get(/databases/staging-v1-users/documents/$(user));
  let conversationsList = userFetched.conversations.conversationsForuser0[0];
  //get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(resource.data.conversations.keys()[0])).data.buyerId == request.auth.uid
  let conversations = "conversation-" + conversationsList;
  let conversationsForuser = get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(conversations)).buyerId.hasAny(userId);
  let conversationsForuser2 = get(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents/$(conversations)).sellerId.hasAny(userId);
  //let listOfConv = getAfter(/databases/staging-v1-conversations/documents).data.values.join(",");
  return conversationsForuser || conversationsForuser2

}
```

Parameters for calling are the logged in user and the userid for the user that needs to be updated.
[/update]

Comment: Have you already checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629167/firestore-rule-on-condition-from-a-different-collection). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: not that specific one, but read about user claims oauth. I actually came up with some security rules that should work, except they didn't. The process is as follows in current code: - create conversation in conv. collection with both user IDs. Save convID to user A, then to user B. User B fails because a user cannot write to another user by sec rule. sec rule exception attempt I tried was: get(/databases/staging-v1-users/documents/$(user)).conversations; for some reason I get : ERROR FirebaseError: 
Service call error even though the path looks good, while a get to conversations succeeds.

Comment: You're getting that error when getting a non existing doc. See this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2067).

Comment: hi,the document exists at the exact path the error gives. Also, the solution in the github issue that is still open does not work, an error about no recursion allowed and overriding the get method occurs. I added the function I am trying to use to the question.

Comment: I simplified the code to omit having to look something up in the conversations DB. I get the same error in the user lookup with get, which seems like a bug to me, so I filed one here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5096 . I cannot 'test' this in production to determine is this is an emulator bug, a general bug, or just a case of misunderstanding something and/or doing something wrong.

Comment: Since I needed stuff to work, I worked around this by creating a cloud function that uses the Admin SDK. Not sure if this bug is related to this : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2067 but that's open for over 2,5 years. The reported one is closed, so I wonder if Google takes this serious? Lost tremendous amount of time debugging, reporting and rewriting and securing. Anything you can push @Doug Stevenson ? Thanks. Pro tip: if you use Firebase, start with security rules enabled and assume 'other document lookup' does not work. cheers